# How do I find out the relative performance of cores on an Android device?

Tags: android, multithreading, arm64

Sometimes, one needs to know how many fast/intermediate/slow cores a physical Android device has, so as to be able to pin threads to them for computationally intensive activities. Is there a way to find out at run-time? There are far too many models in circulation to list in an app.

Answer (score 1):

This is provided by the Linux kernel. From the ADB shell:

```
$ ls -l /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpu_capacity
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2024-02-18 13:20 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpu_capacity
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2024-02-18 13:20 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpu_capacity
...
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2024-02-18 13:20 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpu_capacity
```

The files' contents give the relative performance of the CPUs:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpu_capacity
397
397
397
397
1003
1003
1003
1024
```

The numbers are normalised so that the fastest cpu(s) on the device are reported as 1024, and the slower ones as smaller numbers. These figures are from a Samsung Galaxy A52 5G, running Android 14, with kernel 5.4.233. `/sys` should be easily readable from apps, as opposed to the shell (I don't actually produce apps, just libraries that are tested in the ADB shell).

The oldest device I have access to where `cpu_capacity` exists is a nameless Android 10 tablet with kernel 4.14. It exists in everything with a newer kernel I've tried. It does not exist in Android 9 with kernel 4.9 on an IoT development board. Looking at the list of [Android Common Kernels](https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/kernel/android-common), it appears that devices that launched with Android 11 or later should always have `cpu_capacity`, but devices that launched with earlier versions of Android may lack it.

The higher-numbered cores are usually the fast ones, but this is not always true: a Samsung Galaxy Tab 7A Lite running Android 12 with kernel 4.19 had the faster cores at the lower numbers - and still has after an update to Android 14, still with the same kernel version.

Comment: Nice one, works perfect on Android 14, SM-G998B (Samsung S21 5G Ultra)